# Проблема с кириллицей в Java

Tags: java, кодировка

При вводе русских букв в следующей программе из второго тома книги Хорстманна выводятся иероглифы. Как это исправить? Среда разработки - Eclipse.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * This program implements a simple server that listens to port 8189 and echoes back all
 * client input.
 * @version 1.22 2018-03-17
 * @author Cay Horstmann
 */
public class EchoServer
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      // establish server socket
      try (var s = new ServerSocket(8189))
      {
         // wait for client connection
         try (Socket incoming = s.accept())
         {
            InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outStream = incoming.getOutputStream();
   
            try (var in = new Scanner(inStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            {
               var out = new PrintWriter(
                  new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                  true /* autoFlush */);
      
               out.println("Hello! Enter BYE to exit.");
      
               // echo client input
               var done = false;
               while (!done && in.hasNextLine())
               {
                  String line = in.nextLine();
                  out.println("Echo: " + line);
                  if (line.trim().equals("BYE")) done = true;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте другой чарсет

```
StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
```

Comment: Да, так работает, спасибо, но если добавить в код строку System.out.println("Пользователь ввел: " + line); для вывода на консоль введенного пользователем текста, то на неё также выведутся иероглифы. Например, при вводе текста ПОКА, в программе выведется всё правильно, но вот на консоль Eclipse выведется: Пользователь ввел: ????. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: посмотрите тут https://coderoad.ru/55088169/Java-8-UTF-16-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B0-UTF-8 надуюсь поможет

Comment: И что за минус может поясните?